# What are primordials in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I've just started to read Node.js source code, and something that I notice quite a lot is the use of an object called **primordials**. But I can't seem find where its definition is.

E.g: /node/lib/events.js

```
const {
  Array,
  Boolean,
  Error,
  MathMin,
  NumberIsNaN,
  ObjectCreate,
  ObjectDefineProperty,
  ObjectGetPrototypeOf,
  ObjectSetPrototypeOf,
  ObjectKeys,
  Promise,
  PromiseReject,
  PromiseResolve,
  ReflectApply,
  ReflectOwnKeys,
  Symbol,
  SymbolFor,
  SymbolAsyncIterator
} = primordials;
```

Can someone explain what primordials are and where it is declared?

Comment: After googling "primordials node", I can only see that some variation of what you have here apparently causes problems when there is a mismatch of Gulp and Node.JS. And this isn't really helpful when trying to understand *what* `primordials` is supposed to be. All the error reports go into good detail of how to fix it (remove Gulp, remove dependencies using Gulp, get a compatible version, etc) but none actually explain *why* this is used.

Comment: Spent some more time searching now, and found this video which is about Node.js bootstrap(https://youtu.be/bwiLlcGvFEk?t=280), where she says that primordials is part of V8 context, and it is nothing but the Javascript builtins (Array, Object, globalThis, Boolean, etc). But if anyone have some other information on it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Some brief research revealed [this github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30697) leading to [this node source file](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/141a6e34eed05577edf43ad085a74f330d0559cb/lib/internal/per_context/primordials.js#L5-L7) with some enlightening comments about the purpose of `primordials`:

```
// This file subclasses and stores the JS builtins that come from the VM
// so that Node.js's builtin modules do not need to later look these up from
// the global proxy, which can be mutated by users.
```

So, as mentioned in the issue, the `primordials` object is meant to be a way to guarantee that node builtin modules can access the true untampered globals instead of ones which may have been modified by users.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This is what I was looking for

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Do you know how to access the globals without this? I'm getting a `primordials is not defined` and I think i need to replace primordials with globals. Thanks

Comment: @imaginate You might be interested in this discussion: https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers/issues/344. Support for exposing the internals were added in Node 15.7. Example: `node --expose-internals -r internal/test/binding  -p -e 'Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(global.primordials, "Date")'`

Comment: I had the case that I had to install an older node version to get something running. So check the age what you install and the package.json which node version is requested. Before I got the message "primordials is not defined" too. You might consider something like https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows to install node in different versions.