# ReferenceError: primordials is not defined - Node.js (not gulp)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https

I am trying to edit some of the node.js standard http module files to use locally. HTTP requests work fine, however, when I go to use an HTTPS request, I get this error:

```
} = primordials;
    ^
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
```

Is there a reason for this? I literally copied the Node.js [http/https](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib) code directly, and the only dependency I have is http and https (to compare/test my version in the future). Note that this error is coming from [`/lib/internal/util.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2cc7fa5e7dabdf10bf26efc4ab8dbffd36dba23e/lib/internal/util.js), in the first declaration. I honestly can't figure this error out, as all people with this error seem to be using `gulp` (which I am pretty sure I am not using).

### Edit:

I also looked at other modules, and apparently http also uses some primordial stuff too. I find this odd because I haven't got any errors from http, only `util.js` (when I use https). Not sure if this helps, but I found it interesting

Cheers

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59750976/what-are-primordials-in-node-js) question may be interesting to you.