# How to use cloned Node.js modules instead of native ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, version

I am trying to understand some inner workings of the `stream` module, and looking at the source code is very nice, but there are some components that I just can't understand by looking at the code alone. I'd like to actually be able to put logs in the source code itself, so when I use the module's API, it will log out some stuff. I tried to `git clone` the native modules from Node.js's GitHub, and then run that module's source code as if it was a custom module, example:

`var stream = require("./node/lib/stream")`

When I do this, I get this error:
`primordials is not defined`

I realize that this probably has to do with me not running that module within the context it needs to run in. I'm assuming I need to call a different module first that will define `primordials`. However, I have no idea what I would need to run to have `primordials` be defined. I have verified that the source code that I cloned and the version of Node.js that I am using are the same, namely: v18.15.0

Any help would be absolutely appreciated!

Comment: You can still edit the files inside `/node_modules/` then remove it all and start clean when you are done debugging. If you want to read more about `primordials` there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59750976/what-are-primordials-in-node-js) post that explains it quite well

Comment: Edit what files in `/node_modules/`? Are you referring to the native Node.js modules? I was under the impression that the native Node.js modules are compiled into the `node.exe` executable, and that there really isn't a great way to modify the modules. Before posting my question I already looked inside the `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules` folder, and didn't find any native Node.js modules in there (stream, fs, etc.)

Comment: My bad, I read that wrong. And I think you are right, Windows would need a compiled version where the logs outputs are specified in the sources before getting ingested. I don't think I can really help more than with this l[ink](https://joyeecheung.github.io/blog/2021/07/06/how-does-node-js-load-its-builtins-native-modules/#How-do-I-debug-the-JS-internals-that-are-included-in-the-built-in-startup-snapshot) that explains the NodeJS process for the modules

Comment: So is there not a way to just run the source code from a project as if it was a custom module? e.g. `var stream = require("./node/lib/stream")`?